# Why schedule option isn't available on Pentaho PDI Spoon GUI?

Tags: pentaho, data-integration, pentaho-spoon

I want to schedule a job under Pentaho PDI using the Spoon graphical interface. In the [pentaho documentation](http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fpdi_user_guide%2Ftask_pdi_usr_scheduling_trans_jobs.html) you can see that this is available under Action-->Schedule. But in my case this option isn't there. I'm using Pentaho 6.0.1

[image]

What is exactly the problem in my case ?
Thank's in advance for your help.

Comment: scheduling is probably only available if you use the Pentaho Data Integration Server. If you want to schedule Pentaho jobs without the DI Server, you can for instance use the Task Scheduler and a batch file calling kitchen.bat with your job file.

Comment: Thanks Dirk..Do you have any link for some tutorial or information on how to schedule tasks with spoon ?

Comment: you don't need much. In your PDI directory there is a batch file called kitchen.bat. With command line parameter /file:"<file.kjb>" you can execute a job. With pan.bat (same PDI directory) you can run an individual transformation. I suggest you play around with either .bat file on the command line. After familiarizing yourself with the parameters it is just a case of putting all that in a batch file and scheduling it in the Windows Task Scheduler. Here is the user documentation from Pentaho on kitchen: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Kitchen+User+Documentation

Comment: Thanks Dirk I'll  give it a try :)

Comment: If you are using CE version of Spoon scheduling is not available. It is feature of EE DI server now.

Answer (score -1):

You will not be able to achieve simply using transformation.
You can create one job and there call your transformation, and you will be able to do batch process/scheduling in spoon.

Note : I am talking about community edition.

Comment: down vote for what?
The Solution which I have given is correct only...
Can some moderator look into this.